# postgresql how to cd main folder

Tags: postgresql, users

The right way to run **psql** is

> sudo -u postgres psql

However, what is the right way to open the dir with postgresql files?

> bom@ubuntu:/var/lib/postgresql/9.1$ cd main
>
> -bash: cd: main: Permission denied
>
> bom@ubuntu:/var/lib/postgresql/9.1$ sudo -u postgres cd main/
>
> sudo: cd: command not found

So what the right way?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, broadly?  This doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

is not the "right" way to do it; it is just one way to do it. Another way, which probably does what you want, is

```
sudo -iu postgres   # or sudo -su postgres
cd /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main
psql ...
```

There's also

```
sudo -u postgres bash -c "cd /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main && psql"
```

but I prefer the previous solution.